# How to test geocoder on localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

I want to test geocoder on localhost. 
When i try to do: `request.remote_ip` or `request.location.ip` it return me `::1`.

`request.location.longitude` - it will return nothing.

I tried many solutions that I found on the Internet, but most of them are outdated or simply do not work.

Comment: Use a tunnel like ngrok so that the request is actually coming in from outside.

Comment: You can test "externally" like that, or just add the ability to override your IP in development mode. I sometimes add things like `remote_ip=1.2.3.4` to the params and have a `before_action` that interprets those params. It's only active in development mode, but it makes testing a snap.

Answer (score 1):

I followed @max advice.
Using ngrok is very convenient and solves a number of difficulties.

Comment: This is a very low effort answer and probably the reason why max didn't post it as an answer. A good answer will explain how to use a given tool and why it works, not just say "use _x_."

Answer (score 0):

This is the first result on Google for "geocoder from localhost", so here's an expanded version of @max's advice.

- Go to ngrok.com and register a free account.
- Download and install the binary. You can follow the instruction they provide, or if you're on MacOS and have Homebrew installed, run:

```
brew install ngrok
```

- Connect your account using your authtoken (you should see it as soon as you log in to ngrok.com):

```
ngrok authtoken <your-authtoken>
```

- Run ngrok:

```
ngrok http 80
```

(You may want to replace 80 with a different port such as 8080 or 8081.)

You should see something that looks like this:

```
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                                                                                                            (Ctrl+C to quit)
                                                                                                                                                                                     
Session Status                online                                                                                                                                                 
Account                       <your-name> (Plan: Free)                                                                                                                                   
Version                       2.3.40                                                                                                                                                 
Region                        United States (us)                                                                                                                                     
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                                                                                                                  
Forwarding                    http://<subdomain>.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:80                                                                                                    
Forwarding                    https://<subdomain>.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:80                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                     
Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90                                                                                                            
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

(If you are behind a router you will need to configure it to forward port 80 to your LAN IP.)

Now you can access your localhost via the provided link (`http://<subdomain>.ngrok.io` in the above example).

Note that for geocoding purposes, you will also need to get an API key for a geocoding service (nominatim.openstreetmap.org is giving me a CORS error at time of writing), so this may not be necessary depending on the service you use.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am late at the party, for future viewers, you can override the `request.remote_ip` method to return a valid IP in development.

To do that, override the following method in the `/config/environments/development.rb`

```rb
Rails.application.configure do
  # Set a random IP for testing
  class ActionDispatch::Request
    def remote_ip
     'ANY VALID IP ADDRESS'
    end
  end
end
```

Replace `ANY VALID IP ADDRESS` with a valid IP address. Now when you will call `request.remote_ip`, it will fetch the return value from the overridden method.

You can also return the desired IP from ENV or even generate a random IP every time inside the method if you want.